# Reverse for 'add_to_cart' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['cart/add/(?P<item_id>[^/]+)/$']

Tags: django, django-views

I cant seem to add products/plans to my cart page im getting this error.

This is my views

```
def add_to_cart(request, item_id):
    """ Add plan to shopping cart """
    
    cart = request.session.get('cart', {})
    cart[item_id] = cart.get(item_id, 1)

    request.session['cart'] = cart
    return redirect(reverse('plans'))
```

This is my plans.html - this is a button where im trying to a plan to my cart

```
   <form method="post" action="{% url 'add_to_cart' item.id %}">
                              {% csrf_token %}
                              <div class="text-center">
                                 <span class="input-group-btn">
                                 <button class="btn btn-light color-orange " type="submit">
                                 Add to Cart
                                 </button>
                                 </span>
                              </div>
                           </form>
```

And this is my urls from my cart app

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.view_cart, name='view_cart'),
    path('add/<item_id>/', views.add_to_cart, name='add_to_cart'),
]
```

Would be great if someone could guide me

Comment: Can you show the view which renders the `plans.html` ?

Answer (score 1):

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.view_cart, name='view_cart'),
    # path('add/<item_id>/', views.add_to_cart, name='add_to_cart'),
    path('add/<int:item_id>/', views.add_to_cart, name='add_to_cart'),
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are passing a value with key "item" to the context data in your form HTML, or else "item.id" will be None.